Use attrs or_ validator with mypy
I'm trying to use attrs to define a class that has an attribute that can be either a str or an int. The or_ validator see;s to be exactly what I need but mypy throws an error when using the exact pattern used the doc (modified slightly for my purpose
import attrs


@attrs.define
class C:
  val: int | str = attrs.field(
    validator=attrs.validators.or_(
      attrs.validators.instance_of(int),
      attrs.validators.instance_of(str),
    )
  )

It works just fine and as expected at runtime, but mypy throws the following error:
error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "or_"  [misc]
Any idea of how I can typehint differently or chain the validators to keep type safety but also satisfy mypy?

For anyone coming here from a search turns out I can just do:
import attrs


@attrs.define
class C:
  val: int | str = attrs.field(validator=attrs.validators.instance_of((str, int)))

This may mypy doesn't complain and runtime behavior is unaffected
